# List of changes for EF 4.x DbContext Generator (or POCO Entity Generator)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-generation, poco, dbcontext

Sometimes Visual Studio reminds me that these generators were updated, but I can't find anywhere what was changed and if I would get some benefit from updating my templates.

1. Is there any list of the changes introduced in the several versions of these generators?
2. Do I need to remove and re-add the .tt templates to get the updates or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. I don't think so unless ADO.NET team writes an article related to specific version on their blog.
2. Yes. To use a new version of template you must remove old .tt files and add new one.

Comment: Ok, that's what I feared. Thanks.